# Toggle event handler if the body is clicked, but not if the click is on [some element]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I want to make an event listener that triggers some code when a certain element is clicked, and one that toggles some code if anything but that element is clicked. So far, all I've come up with is making two handlers, one for the body and one for the element, and slightly delaying the code with `setTimeout()` to avoid the two handlers conflicting. It looks very ugly and, well, not right. Is there a better way to do what I need here? Or, is there an "all-but-this-element" handler I can use? I have been doing this with jQuery, so answers dependent on the library are welcome and preferred.

Comment: I'm confused, didn't understand the question !

Comment: Simple: I want code *a* (and not code *b*) to be run when a certain element is clicked, and code *b* (and not code *a*) when anything else that isn't that element is clicked.

Comment: Only you need is eventhandler for `body`. Just check if the click was on that particular element, then do this or that.

Comment: Please check [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/click).

Comment: [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/HDsLF/) ?

Comment: Rather something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9JRH3/1/), if I've understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind the click to all elements not to an element with id "div1",  you can use like:

```
$('body').on('click', ':not(#div1)', function(){ 

});
```

Comment: Nice! Can I add two "not"s?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want something like this (if I understood the question)

**HTML:**

```
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName=='BODY') 
    {
        // clickd on body
    }
    else if($(e.target).attr('id')=='btn')
    {
        // clickd on button
    }
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HDsLF/1/).

Comment: `that triggers some code when a certain element is clicked, and one that toggles some code if anything but that element is clicked` +1 anyway, OP can edit the code to do that too ; ).